# Unicode is being written to my files

Tags: python, logging, unicode

I have a program that writes to output and writes to a file. The output is colored using a function that looks like this:

```
def set_color(org_string, level=None):
    """
    set the console log color, this will kinda mess with the file log but whatever
    """
    color_levels = {
        10: "\033[36m{}\033[0m",       # DEBUG
        20: "\033[32m{}\033[0m",       # INFO *default
        30: "\033[33m{}\033[0m",       # WARNING
        40: "\033[31m{}\033[0m",       # ERROR
        50: "\033[7;31;31m{}\033[0m"   # FATAL/CRITICAL/EXCEPTION
    }
    if level is None:
        return color_levels[20].format(org_string)
    else:
        return color_levels[int(level)].format(org_string)
```

How you use this is using a logger:

```
# console logger and file logger settings
logger = logging.getLogger("zeus-log")
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
file_handler = logging.FileHandler(
    filename=create_log_name(), mode="a+"
)
file_handler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
console_handler = logging.StreamHandler()
console_handler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
file_format = logging.Formatter(
    '%(asctime)s;%(name)s;%(levelname)s;%(message)s'
)
console_format = logging.Formatter(
    "[%(asctime)s %(levelname)s] %(message)s", "%H:%M:%S"
)
file_handler.setFormatter(file_format)
console_handler.setFormatter(console_format)
logger.addHandler(console_handler)
logger.addHandler(file_handler)
```

When you call the logger, to set the color:

```
logger.info(set_color(
    "test"
))
```

Will output green text, or whatever color you want. The problem is when it writes to the log file it will also write the `set_color` function info and the output looks like this:

```
2017-09-29 14:25:50,277;zeus-log;DEBUG;[36mchecking if the application has been run before...[0m
2017-09-29 14:25:50,278;zeus-log;DEBUG;[36mverifying operating system...[0m
2017-09-29 14:25:50,278;zeus-log;DEBUG;[36malready ran, skipping...[0m
2017-09-29 14:25:50,279;zeus-log;DEBUG;[36mrunning with options '{'runInVerbose': True, 'useRandomAgent': True, 'dorkToUse': 'inurl:php?id=10'}'...[0m
2017-09-29 14:25:50,280;zeus-log;INFO;[32mlog file being saved to '/home/baal/bin/python/zeus-scanner/log/zeus-log-47.log'...[0m
2017-09-29 14:25:50,280;zeus-log;DEBUG;[36mgrabbing random user-agent from '/home/baal/bin/python/zeus-scanner/etc/agents.txt'...[0m
2017-09-29 14:25:50,281;zeus-log;DEBUG;[36musing default search engine (Google)...[0m
2017-09-29 14:25:50,282;zeus-log;INFO;[32musing default search engine...[0m
2017-09-29 14:25:50,282;zeus-log;INFO;[32mstarting dork scan with query 'inurl:php?id=10'...[0m
2017-09-29 14:25:50,282;zeus-log;DEBUG;[36mchecking for user-agent and proxy configuration...[0m
2017-09-29 14:25:50,285;zeus-log;INFO;[32mattempting to gather query URL...[0m
```

Is there a way I can write to the log file and get rid of the unicode strings along with the color calls (`[<NUM>m`)?

To clarify `SO` removed the issue from the above output, here is an image of the problem:

[image: data]

As you can see there are weird *squares* in front of the ANSI escape sequences

Comment: You can't write unicode to files.  You can only write bytes.

Comment: What Unicode strings are you talking about? Everything in your example appears to be ASCII.

Comment: What does this have to do with Unicode? You are writing the same bytes in both cases; the difference is that the terminal interprets them to mean "change the color" instead of displaying the bytes in some visible form.

Comment: I can't see any Unicode here. I can see [ANSI escape sequences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code)

Comment: Added an image of what I'm talking about

Comment: @wim guess I'm talking about the bytes then

Comment: @MarkRansom `SO` removed the issue from the output, I have added a picture of the actual problem.

Comment: Those squares aren't Unicode, they are the ASCII ESC character `\033`.

Comment: Is there a reason you can't just replace the `set_color` function so it doesn't actually output the escape sequences?

Comment: @MarkRansom That makes sense. Can I prevent them from being written to a file? The program relies on it to much at this point, it would be more work to replace the function and it would cause another requirement to get output in the console.

Comment: Why is the code doing the logging handling the color instead of the logger itself?

Comment: The usual approach is to test if the output device is a terminal, and if it's not then you don't emit the ANSI escape codes, that's what programs like `ls` and `grep` do (unless you over-ride that behaviour with the `--color=always` option). It's _much_ easier to do that than to try to filter out the escape codes further downstream.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams because when I first started I thought it was a freaking brilliant idea to use as little requirements as possible, now it's starting to bite me in the ass and I'm realizing how damn stupid I am.

Comment: Taking a quick look at `logging`, you may want to create your own `ColorFormatter` that overrides `Formatter.format()` to add the color for the level, and then use that with `console_handler`.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams  couldn’t that cause even more problems since you’re overriding the method that would also be passed to the file log?

Comment: @13aal: The Formatter gets set per Handler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest solution is to modify the `set_color` function so that it returns the string unmodified, with no color sequences added. Based on the comments it appears this isn't an option.

Once the file is written to disk, it's a single Linux command to remove those escape sequences:

```
sed -r 's/.\[[0-9]+m//' logfile
```

Comment: This seems like the best approach, you could write to a temp file and somehow grep out the escape sequences, then write it to the log

Comment: @MarkRansom this doesn't work because the file isn't created until the program ends

Comment: @wahwahwah how are you inspecting that output then?

Comment: @MarkRansom by looking at the file after the program ends. Do you think if I opened the file, substituted out the escape sequences, cleared the file, and then rewrote it that would work?

Comment: @wahwahwah then it *does* work, because you're waiting until the program ends anyway. What you do with the output after stripping out the escape sequences is up to you, the command I gave just runs it to the console. You can redirect to another file or whatever you want, Linux gives you lots of options.